# Custom Docker Image with Azure CLI base for authentication

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, dockerfile, containers

I'm building a .NET Core application that I would like to deploy via Azure Devops build pipeline.  The pipeline will build, test and deploy using Docker containers.

I have successfully built the first docker image for my application using the following `Dockerfile` and am now attempting to run it on my local machine before using it in the pipeline:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
MAINTAINER yummylumpkins <yummy@lumpkins.com>
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish MyAPIApp -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPIApp.dll"]
```

Running this image inside a docker container locally crashes because my application uses `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` to attempt to fetch a token from Azure Services that will then be used to fetch secrets from Azure Key Vault. 
 The local docker container that the image runs from does not have the authorization to access Azure Services. 
 The docker container error output looks like this:

```
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Connection refused
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. /bin/bash: az: No such file or directory
```

After doing a lot of research (and getting some positive feedback here) it would appear that the best way to authorize the locally running docker container is to build the image on top of an Azure CLI base image from Microsoft, then use `az login --service-principal -u <app-url> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>` somewhere during the build/run process to authorize the local docker container.

I have successfully pulled the Azure CLI image from Microsoft (`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli`) and can run it via `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli`. The container runs with the Azure CLI command line and I can log in via bash, but that's as far as I've come.

The next step would be to layer this Azure CLI image into my previous Dockerfile during the image build, but I am unsure to do this.  I've tried the following:

```
# New base image is now Azure CLI
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
RUN az login -u yummylumpkins -p yummylumpkinspassword

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
MAINTAINER yummylumpkins <yummy@lumpkins.com>
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish MyAPIApp -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPIApp.dll"]
```

But this still doesn't work, the process still results in the same error mentioned above (I think because the login does not persist when adding the new `dotnet core` layer.  My question is, how would I explicitly build Azure CLI image into my dockerfile/image building process with an `azure login` command to authorize the docker container, persist the authorization, and then set a command to run the app (MyAPIApp.dll) with the persisted authorization?

Or, am I taking the completely wrong approach with this?  Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: `I have successfully built the first docker image for my application using the following Dockerfile and am now attempting to run it on my local machine before using it in the pipeline.` Did you mean you build the docker image succeed locally or through Azure DevOps build pipeline? If through Azure DevOps build, are you using self-host agent or host agent with Azure DevOps?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Hello there...to be specific, I built the docker image locally through my local cli (on my dev computer).  When I run the `docker run` command from my local CLI (*not* inside the devops pipeline), the image starts up but shortly crashes because the docker container that the image is running in does not have access to get tokens via `AzureServiceTokenProvider()`. When I say locally, I mean on my local dev environment, not DevOps.

Comment: Hi yummylumpkins According to your description, this issue seems not too much related to Azure DevOps. If you are using `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` . The AzureServiceTokenProvider class caches the token in memory and retrieves it from Azure AD just before expiration. So, you no longer have to check the expiration before calling the GetAccessTokenAsync method. Just call the method when you want to use the token. More details take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication

Comment: According to above link check if this helps: Common issues across environments - **Unauthorized access, access denied, forbidden, or similar error**

The principal used doesn't have access to the resource it's trying to access. Grant either **your user account** or the App Service's MSI "Contributor" **access to a resource.** Which one depends on whether you're running the sample on your local computer or deployed in Azure to your App Service. Some resources, like key vaults, also have their own access policies that you use grant access to principals, such as users, apps, and groups.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Thanks for weighing in again.  You are correct w/ `AzureServiceTokenProvider()`, however, in order to get the token, it makes a call to Azure services:

`For local development, AzureServiceTokenProvider fetches tokens using Visual Studio, Azure command-line interface (CLI), or Azure AD Integrated Authentication. Each option is tried sequentially and the library uses the first option that succeeds. If no option works, an AzureServiceTokenProviderException exception is thrown with detailed information.`

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Continuing from my last comment. . . so the issue here is that when the app runs locally from my IDE, behind the scenes, `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` has no issue grabbing the token from Azure, because Azure can see the request is coming from my IDE.  When the same application is run inside a docker container, however, the same exact process (`AzureServiceTokenProvider()`) is denied a token, because Azure doesn't recognize the docker container that the application is running in.  Hence the need for me to authorize inside the container before running the app.

Comment: Thanks for you kindly sharing.Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an update with an answer here just in case anyone else has a similar problem.  I haven't found any other solutions to this so I had to make my own.  Below is my Dockerfile.  Right now the image is sitting at 1GB so I will definitely need to go through and optimize, but I'll explain what I did:

```
#1 Install .NET Core SDK Build Environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

#2 Build YummyApp
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish YummyAppAPI -c Release -o out

#3 Install Ubuntu Base Image
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER yummylumpkins <yummy@lumpkins.com>
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
EXPOSE 80

#4 Install package dependencies & .NET Core SDK
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl bash dos2unix wget dpkg \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && apt-get update \
    && add-apt-repository universe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1 \
    && apt-get update \
    && rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

#5 Copy project files from earlier SDK build
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

#6 Install Azure CLI for AppAuthorization
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

#7 Login to Azure Services and run application
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN dos2unix entrypoint.sh && chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Step 1 - Install .NET Core SDK Build Environment:** We start with using .NET Core SDK as a base image to build my application.  It should be noted that I have a big app with one solution and multiple project files.  The API project is dependent on the other projects.

**Step 2 - Build YummyApp:**  We copy the entire project structure from our local directory to our working directory inside the docker image (/app).  Just in case anyone is curious, my project is a basic API app.  It looks like this:

```
[YummyApp]
  |-YummyAppDataAccess
     |YummyAppDataAccess.csproj
  |-YummyAppInfrastructure
     |YummyAppInfrastructure.csproj
  |-YummyAppAPI
    |-YummyAppAPI.csproj
  |-YummyAppServices
    |-YummyAppServices.csproj
  |-YummyApp.sln
```

After we copy everything over, we build/publish a Release configuration of the app.

**Step 3 - Install Ubuntu Base Image:** We start a new layer using Ubuntu.  I initially tried to go with Alpine Linux but found it almost impossible to install Azure CLI on it without having to do some really hacky workarounds so I went w/ Ubuntu for the ease of installation.

**Step 4 - Install package dependencies & .NET Core SDK:** Inside the Ubuntu layer we set our work directory and install/update a bunch of libraries including our .NET Core SDK.  It should be noted that I needed to install `dos2unix` for a shell script file I had to run later on. . .I will explain later.

Note: I initially tried to install .NET Core Runtime only as it is more lightweight and would bring this image down to about 700MB (from 1GB) but for some reason when I tried to run my application at the end of the file (Step 7) I was getting an error saying that no runtime was found.  So I went back to the SDK.

**Step 5 - Copy project files from earlier SDK Build:** To save space, I copied the built project files from  the first 'build image' over to this Ubuntu layer to save some space (about 1GB worth).

**Step 6 - Install Azure CLI:**  In order to authorize my application to fetch a token from Azure Services, normally I use `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`.  This package provides a method called `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` which (via my IDE) authorizes my application to connect to Azure Services to get a token that is then used to access the Azure Key Vault.  *This whole issues started because my application is unable to do this from within a docker container, because Azure doesn't recognize the request coming from the container itself.*

So in order to work around this, we need to login via `az login` in the Azure CLI, inside the container, before we start the app.

**Step 7 - Login to Azure Services and run application:** Now it's showtime.  I had two different problems to solve here.  I had to figure out how to execute `az login` and `dotnet YummyAppAPI.dll` when this container would be fired up.  But Dockerfiles only allow one `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to be executed at runtime, so I found a workaround.  By making a shell script file (entrypoint.sh) I was able to put both commands into this file and then execute that one file.

After setting this up, I was getting an error with the `entrypoint.sh` that read something like this: `entrypoint.sh: executable file not found in $PATH`.  I found out that I had to change the permissions of this file using `chmod` because otherwise, my docker container was unable to access it.  That made the file visible, but the file was still unable to execute. I was receiving another error: `Standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused “no such file or directory”`

After some more digging, it turns out that this problem happens when you try to use a .sh file created in Windows on a Linux-based system.  So I had to install `dos2unix` to convert this file to something Linux compatible.  I also had to make sure the file was formatted correctly.  For anyone curious, this is what my `entrypoint.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

az login -u yummy@lumpkins.com -p ItsAlwaysYummy
dotnet /app/YummyAppAPI.dll

exec "$@"
```

**Note:** The login and password is hard-coded. . .I know this is bad practice (in fact, it's terrible) however, this is *only* for my local machine and will never see production.  The next step would be to introduce environment variables with a service principle login.  Since this deployment will eventually happen in the Azure Devops pipeline, I can inject those ENV vars straight into the devops pipeline YAML so that all of this happens without me ever punching in credentials; they will come straight from the Key Vault where they are stored.

Lastly, the size of this container is huge (1GB) and it does need to be optimized if it will be updated/built regularly.  I will continue working on that but I am open to suggestions on how best to do that moving forward.

Thanks again all.

Comment: To reduce your docker container size, you could start from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 instead of ubuntu:latest